# Is there a way to navigate through library sources while using IntelliJ + Bazel + Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, bazel

When using IntelliJ for Scala with the Bazel plugin, you can navigate through your source code by using `Ctrl + Click` (go to definition), but, if you go to an imported library, you get a decompiled Java version, this seems to be caused because the library sources weren't downloaded, there is no button to download them automatically.

I would like to get a reliable way to import bazel projects and get the scala library sources downloaded to be able to navigate through them, this is not a problem with SBT.

Ideally, this can be done by configuration, I'd be happy to see fixes by updating any of the involved plugings too.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the source jars aren't downloaded. How does the project fetch jars from Maven?

Comment: Excatly, that's what I would like to know how to set up, it's bazel specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Maven artifact resolver like [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/), you can fetch source jars alongside the main artifacts using `fetch_sources = True`. The IntelliJ plugin will then automatically detect the source jar and navigate to it if it exists.

```py
maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.12:7.2.27",
        "org.scalaz:scalaz-concurrent_2.12:7.2.27",
        # ...
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],
    fetch_sources = True,
)
```

Check out a Scala example project [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/blob/master/examples/scala_akka/WORKSPACE).

Comment: I'll try, do you know how to get the sources from projects imported from github? Thanks.

Comment: You can manually wire up a JAR using java_import.srcjar https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_import

Comment: After trying your solution, I have actually tried `scala_akka` project by importing the `rules_jvm_external` as an external module instead of a local repository, added the `fetch_sources = True` that you indicated, then, Imported the project on IntelliJ `2018.3.6`, and while opening the `Server.scala`, the external libraries aren't recognized, I'm using bazel `0.24.1`, and here you can find my [patch](https://github.com/AlexITC/rules_jvm_external/commit/9c7a93d4d186db08fb4b4424684600287b678686), am I missing any steps?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on 2018.3.6. The `akka` dependencies resolve correctly for me, even to the sources. Have you tried syncing?

Comment: Yes, after clicking on `partially sync`, then, intellij says I haven't set up the scala SDK, after choosing one, I get Scala standard library resolved but none of the external dependencies is resolved.

Comment: I did not have to set up the Scala SDK. I imported a new Bazel project by pointing it at rules_jvm_external/examples/scala_akka, and enabled Scala in the IntelliJ project view file under the "additional_languages" section. I think you may have missed the last step.

Comment: Enabling `Scala` on the `additional_languages` languages section while importing the project did the trick, thanks a lot!